# array strings to underscore and lowercase

Tags: arrays, string, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-3.0

I have this array and need to lowercase the values and add underscores quickly as this may contain thousands of results. I am using cakephp 3.0 beta btw.

What I have so far:

```
$a = [
    (int) 0 => 'Dasdf',
    (int) 1 => 'FasDfgh',
    (int) 2 => 'CdfDhy',
    (int) 3 => 'WrdTghte',
    (int) 4 => 'StdFgh',
]
```

I realize that I may be way off but these were the functions I was considering using. Also I realize my usage may be way off.

```
$res = Hash::map($a, '{n}', array($this, 'noop'));
$underscore = Inflector::underscore('{Foo}');
$res = Hash::extract($a['{n}'] , Inflector::humanize($underscore) );
```

This is the result I need:
    $a = [
        (int) 0 => 'dasdf',
        (int) 1 => 'fas_dfgh',
        (int) 2 => 'cdf_dhy',
        (int) 3 => 'wrd_tghte',
        (int) 4 => 'std_fgh',
    ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thousands of results shouldn't be a big deal - this is very light logic.

```
$strings = array('Dasdf', 'FasDfgh', 'CdfDhy');
foreach($strings as &$string) {
    $string = strtolower(Inflector::underscore($string));
}
```